# Are there any similarities in the DNA of a humans and animals?

Tags: dna

As the title says, i've been wondering if there are any similarities between the DNA of humans and the DNA of animals?
Like, maybe monkeys are more similiar in their DNA to humans, than dogs are (to humans)?

Thanks in advance, sorry if there are any english mistakes.

Comment: see: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/same-dna-vs-genes

Answer (score 4):

- Genome-wide variation from one **human being** to another can be up to 0.5% (99.5% similarity)
- **Chimpanzees** are 96% to 98% similar to humans, depending on how it is calculated. (http://genome.wellcome.ac.uk/doc_WTD020730.html)
- **Cats** have 90% of homologous genes with humans, 82% with dogs, 80% with cows, 79% with chimpanzees, 69% with rats and 67% with mice. (http://genome.cshlp.org/content/17/11/1675.full)
- **Cows** (*Bos taurus*) are 80% genetically similar to humans (http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/content/full/324/5926/522)
- 75% of **mouse** genes have equivalents in humans (http://www.plosbiology.org/article/info:doi/10.1371/journal.pbio.1000112), 90% of the mouse genome could be lined up with a region on the human genome (http://www.genome.gov/page.cfm?pageID=10005831) 99% of mouse genes turn out to have analogues in humans (http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v420/n6915/full/420509a.html)
- The **fruit fly** (*Drosophila*) shares about 60% of its DNA with humans (http://www.genome.gov/10005835).
- About 60% of **chicken** genes correspond to a similar human gene. (http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2004/12/041208230523.htm)