# Why do humans share over 99% of their genomes?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, human-genetics

From Wikipedia

> The haploid human genome (23 chromosomes) is about 3 billion base pairs long and contains around 30,000 genes.[33] Since every base pair can be coded by 2 bits, this is about 750 megabytes of data. An individual somatic (diploid) cell contains twice this amount, that is, about 6 billion base pairs. Men have fewer than women because the Y chromosome is about 57 million base pairs whereas the X is about 156 million. Since individual genomes vary in sequence by less than 1% from each other, the variations of a given human's genome from a common reference can be losslessly compressed to roughly 4 megabytes.

Why do humans share over 99% of their genomes? Is it a historical accident or a result of selective pressure? If a zygote differed in 5% of the base sequence from the common human genome would it automatically be unviable or could it eventually become a healthy baby?

Comment: Dogs vary by as much as 25% and  I think the concencus is interbreeding did happen with other human species, so it could probably be much higher, but not just any genes either.

Comment: Humans are a very, very young species, we began diverging on the order of 100,000s of years, compared to e.g. crocodiles which have been around for 200m years, so there has barely been any time for differences to accumulate.

Comment: But I'm also not sure this question is well posed. Why wouldn't they share 99% of their genomes?

Comment: Let's say there is potential human genome that only shares 70% with the common human genome and that results in you being able to run twice as fast as Usain Bolt. Wouldn't that be evolutionarily advantageous at least in some environments? Wouldn't mutations eventually get us there?

Comment: @SKG that's kind of too hypothetical to answer really. If they only shared 70% then they sure wouldn't be human in any sense we know. Evolution happens incrementally, not in massive step changes which would alter 30% of the genome.

Comment: I guess if the only option to make embryos is natural reproduction then the question cannot be meaningfully considered. However now that we have several tools for targeted mutations (and also gamma rays for untargeted mutations) I think it does become possible to make an embryo sharing 70% with the common human genome and to put it in a womb. It is probably unethical but I wondered if any expert has written about this.

Comment: Relevant: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9172/do-apes-and-humans-share-99-of-dna-or-99-of-genes-what-is-the-difference and also https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48084/perplexing-by-the-way-of-estimating-the-shared-or-different-genes-between-humans?rq=1 Make sure when you think and talk about %s of "shared" DNA you know what type of "shared" you mean.

Comment: Because the 99% is what makes humans human, of course.  The rest is just minor variation. I would imagine that ANY particular species would have a similar percentage of common genome.  Humans (and other mammals) share a large fraction of DNA with plants, because that's what constructs the basic mechanisms of life, such as cell membranes, ion channels, DNA/RNA replication, &c.

Comment: @jamesqf Are there any other species that have 23 chromosome pairs and the same number of base pairs in each chromosome as humans? Otherwise I don't understand how can we compare the genomes of different species (it sounds like comparing strings of different lengths).

Comment: @SKG just to give you context, the measured divergence between humans and other great apes is ~1%, and there is complete reproductive divergence between these organisms (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0002929707640968). To be clear, these percentages reflect the subset of the genome that is comparable ("alignable") in the first place. Any two humans probably have different numbers of bp in their genomes, due to hypervariable repetitive regions. Moreover, it is relatively easy to blow big holes in the human genome ("aneuploidy"), but it has a tendency to kill the human.

Comment: also... "Wouldn't mutations eventually get us there?" i mean... there is a nonzero probability of massive divergence like 30%. After all, evolution does happen on that scale given hundreds of millions of years. But it's like randomly flipping 30% of the bits on your computer and expecting it to keep working. Maybe a very controlled "intelligent design" of bit-flips could get you there, but trial-and-error will take trillions of iterations or more. If you want intelligent design, well, we have to understand the code before we can start hacking! We don't understand genomes that well.

Comment: @SKG: As I understand it - and this is not my field, so I'm very far from being an expert - what gets compared are genes.  For instance, there are a family of genes that control the formation of various types of potassiim ion channels.  Each gene is made up of a number of base pairs, and can be located on any chromosome. The particular genes can be isolated and compared: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_channel

Comment: @Armand: You have a couple of undefineds in that experiment.  First, what is the average number of offspring per individual?  Second, what fraction of those mutations result in non-viable offspring?

Comment: @Armand tl;dr Your thought experiment is really talking about a different measurement from the OP's cited number. Generally, estimates of substitution rate say ~$1x10^{-8}$ (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-00323-y), 2 orders of magnitude lower than yours. It doesn't include high mutation rate loci, but those usually aren't alignable anyways so they wouldn't show up in this frequently cited estimate. 1% is probably closer to a "true" measure and ~$1x10^{-6}$ might be closer to a "true" mutation rate, but that is counting a bunch of stuff that people don't tend to count.

Comment: @MaximilianPress OK, sorry for the distraction here.

Answer (score 3):

No one seems to be able to decide whether this question is worth answering or not, I will put one down just to bring closure, summarizing some of the discussion in the comments. I think that the question merits answering because the genetics community honestly hasn't done a good job of messaging on this topic.

It's a little involved, so I'll break it into parts. It's a bit long, so for a tl;dr you can skip to the conclusions.

### what does "less than 1% different" mean?

First, it's important to know what the widely cited statistic of [~0.1% difference](http://humanorigins.si.edu/evidence/genetics#:%7E:text=While%20the%20genetic%20difference%20between,humans%20to%20the%20same%20degree.) between the average pair of humans means. It means that, of *alignable sequence*, if you look at ~1000 bp, approximately 1 bp will be different. As a point of comparison, most great apes (including humans) differ from each other by 1-2% by this measure.

However, not all of the human genome is thus "alignable" even between two humans. When I say "alignable", what I mean is that I can take a snippets of two sequences (say, a 100 bp region) and 1) confidently determine that the area is the same on the two genomes, and 2) we can actually associate specific ACGT with each other between the two sequence. Such a 100bp snippet is then "alignable" with regard to the two genomes.

When sequence is not alignable, that usually means that it shows redundancy in the genome, which is to say that it is present in more than one copy, or a similar enough sequence is present that my confidence in a unique placement is low.

In other words, the 0.1% statistic is actually based on the subset of the genome where we can perform confident comparisons. If this minority of the genome were representative, this would not be an issue. But the alignable portion of the genome is highly non-representative, as it contains most of the genes that we care so much about, and none of the big important structural pieces like telomeres and centromeres. This non-alignable region is in part so hard to analyze because it has a much higher mutation rate than the rest of the genome; in other words, we expect the non-alignable regions to be more variable than the alignable regions. Probably much of the genetic variation among humans occurs in these regions.

So the 0.1% estimate is a significant underestimate of divergence. It is nonetheless a useful heuristic for thinking about relative degrees of divergence.

### Why don't humans vary genetically more than they do?

This is, I believe, the heart of your question. Whether the true difference is 0.1%, or 1%, or 5%, one could ask why it isn't 30% instead, as you do in your comment. It seems that you are at least somewhat interested in this from an adaptationist point of view, namely that one can imagine that all that extra variation could be helpful in making humans "better", however we happen to define "better" (faster, stronger, smarter, disease-resistant).

This framing is closely related to the classic SE Bio catchall question "[Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont)" The common logic being: "I can imagine a way that an organism could be better, why isn't it *already* better in that way?" I'm not sure that you are specifically interested in that as opposed to a more general curiosity, otherwise it'd be easier to mark your question as a duplicate and move on.

There are several related reasons I can think of why the level of divergence is what it is, I'll try to hit them here:

#### 1. Evolution is slow

Commenter @user438383 got at this a bit in comments, noting that humans are very young in evolutionary terms and asking why *not* 99%? There's some logic under there that isn't stated that I'll try to unpack.

Other commenter @Armand posted and then deleted (after a too-pointed critique from me) a version of a thought-experiment: let's build a toy model of evolution and plug in some numbers and see what comes out. For example, we could then say that the expected probability of a site remaining the same across $n$ generations is $(1 - \mu)^n$ in a single lineage assuming no back-mutation, where $\mu$ is the mutation rate. We know that the average site in the (alignable) genome has a mutation rate of around $\mu = 1 \times 10^{-8}$. So if we were to calculate that probability for the average site for $n = 100,000$ generations (~3 million years, way older than anatomically ), we get:

$ Pr(no\_change\_at\_position) = (1-10^{-8})^{100000} = 0.9990005$

So, under this deeply simple-minded model with arbitrarily defined numbers, you actually get very little expected change at the position even for rather large time-scales. There are tons of problems with this model, as alluded to by @jamesqf, namely that we ignore population dynamics. But it should at least illustrate the scales that we are working with here.

#### 2. Many/most mutations are shared, due to coalescence

Another fun subtlety is that, of the mutations that do occur in our toy model in (1), many or most of those mutations are expected to be shared between all humans due to [coalescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalescent_theory). Briefly, under reasonable assumptions about breeding dynamics, you expect that all humans share a surprisingly recent common ancestor. So there is no *variation*, because all humans share the mutations.

This issue is exacerbated by so-called population bottlenecks, which are [inferred to have happened fairly recently for humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toba_catastrophe_theory).

#### 3. Most mutations don't matter.

We have [known for some time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_theory_of_molecular_evolution#:%7E:text=The%20neutral%20theory%20of%20molecular,alleles%20that%20are%20selectively%20neutral.) that most of the mutations that do occur have no effect, and allele frequencies suggest no selection occurs on most genetic variation. So there does not seem to be any particular advantage or benefit for humans from having more mutations.

In the absence of selection maintaining a new allele, [it is usually lost from the population due to random chance, i.e. "genetic drift"](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/genetic-drift-201/#:%7E:text=Genetic%20drift%20is%20common%20after,and%20decrease%20the%20gene%20pool.).

#### 4. Mutations that matter are mostly bad.

Of the mutations that do have some effect, [selection mostly tends to remove them because they are deleterious](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrg2146). These alleles are removed from the population at high frequencies, leading to an incentive to [minimize mutation rate](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2910838/) to maximize viable offspring.

In fact, the burden of past slightly deleterious mutations retained in the population is a significant force in evolution ([the "mutational load"](https://www.blackwellpublishing.com/ridley/a-z/Mutational_load.asp#:%7E:text=Mutational%20load%20is%20the%20total,and%20its%20production%20by%20mutation.)); it is simpler to just not have these mutations in the first place.

### Conclusion: you should expect human genomes to differ very little from each other in the alignable regions.

To sum up:

1. There has not been enough time to introduce all that many mutations into the alignable region of the human population genome.
2. Of the mutations that occurred, most are shared by all humans.
3. Of the mutations that occurred, most have no effect, of which many are lost due to genetic drift.
4. Of the mutations that occurred and had some effect, most were deleterious and were purged by selection.

Comment: Did you mean unalignable or "ambiguous location for short-reads"?

Comment: mm, I suppose that it's worth clarifying that repeatmasker is the latter, which is definitely an overstatement relative to the more traditional "alignable". I will look around and see if there is a better estimate somewhere.

Comment: On second thought, RepeatMasker is likely closer to this than any alternatives. But I can certainly improve the explanation to make it less about short read mapping.

Comment: I can't help as I'm just discovering the topic but nanopore website referenced [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41588-021-00865-4) which seems to be exactly doing this, evaluating the true underlying diversity not captured by standard pipelines

Comment: @reuns, I'm really thinking of the regions that would not be properly alignable even if we had the perfect full telomere-to-telomere assemblies that the nanopore website refers to. These are significant regions including the telomeres, centromeres, pericentromeres, transposable element sequences, etc. In consideration of your point, I have attempted to reframe the alignability section of my answer to correspond more closely to this, as I was unable to locate a reliable estimate of alignability proportions. It is after all not really important what the exact amount is for this answer.

Comment: I think you left out an important point: the differences between humans ARE trivial.  A lot of what goes into making a human also goes into making any primate; much of that is shared with all mammals, mammals share a great deal with other vertbrates, and so on back to LUCA.  For instance, this paper compares the HOX genes (which are fundamental to regulating the body plan) of sharks, various fish, mice, and humans: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC403639/  And then there's what we share with archaea: http://www.sci-news.com/biology/archaeal-chromosomes-07611.html

Comment: @jamesqf I think that this is implicit, after all the question could be reframed as "why are the differences between humans so trivial?" That said, I could do a better job making it explicit.